# Excel VBA to parse SQL Connection Strings

Tags: sql, excel, vba, connection-string, oledb

I have an Excel VBA that connects to a SQL DB using the connection strings, but I would like to know if it's possible to parse into the connection string from a cell?  For instance, if I have `SQLSVR1\Instance1` in cell `B2` and `Databas1` in `B3` can i get that to be put into the connection strings like the following:

```
objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb; Data Source=**"B2"**; Initial Catalog=**"B3"**; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally possible:

```
objMyConn.ConnectionString =  "Provider=sqloledb; Data Source=" & range("B2").value & "; Initial Catalog=" & range("B3").value &"; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

This basically concatenates your string with the values in those cells.

[Range.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) documents.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible as **EoinS** mentioned. But please be aware to determine your worksheets. For the case you would like to define the connection strings on another worksheet. Try something like this:

```
Dim wb as workbook, ws as worksheet

Set wb = Thisworkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("TheNameofYourWorksheetsWithYourConnectionsDefined")

''Get Cnxn details
sDsn = wsc.Cells(wsc.Range("YourLabeloftheCell").Row + 1,   wsc.Range("YourLabeloftheCell").Column).Value
sUser = wsc.Cells(wsc.Range("YourLabeloftheCell").Row + 2, wsc.Range("YourLabeloftheCell").Column).Value
sPwd = wsc.Cells(wsc.Range("YourLabeloftheCell").Row + 3, wsc.Range("YourLabeloftheCell").Column).Value

sSql= GetRangeString(Worksheets("SQL").Range("A17:A22"))
check = DbSelectQueryToSheet(sDsn, "", sUser, sPwd, sSql, Worksheets("TargetWorksheet").Range("A1"), True)
```

Hope, this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help - much appreciated